# Add images from external URL in WYSIWYG Editor

Tags: media, 8, wysiwyg

I am new to Drupal 8, and having some trouble with inline images.

### Need

I store my images on Flickr, and want add them as inline images (in editor) in articles on my Drupal 8 site. I also need to **set captions**, and **alignment** for those images.

I **don't** need Drupal to manage the image files for me.

### Problem

- Drupal 8 uses a customized CKEditor Image Upload dialog, which does not support inserting images from a URL and only supports uploading images to the web server.
- When I double clicked on a Flickr image added via HTML code, the image dialog won't show up.

### My current workaround

- In `Configuration -> Text formats and editors`:

  - Disable image uploads;
  - Turn off the filters `Track images uploaded via a Text Editor`, `Caption images` and `Align images`;
  - Allow `align` attributes for `<img>`, allow `<figure>` and `<caption>` tag. (Or just use Full HTML and don't filter tags)
- Hard-core the image (`<img src="....">`) via Source in CKEditor;
- Switch to WYSIWYG, double click on the image. Now **the origin CKEditor image dialog** (not the Drupal one) will show up which allows me to add captions or set alignment.

### Further Observations

Images added this way will have code like `<figure><img align="left"></img><caption>Caption</caption></figure>` even in editing mode.

Images managed by Drupal (if `Caption images` and `Align images` are on) will have alignment and caption added as `data-caption` and `data-align` attributes on `<img>` (no `<figure>` in editing, but will expand into that structure when viewing).

---

### My Questions

- How to disable the `DrupalImage` and `DrupalImageCaption` plugins (at `core/modules/ckeditor/src/Plugin/CKEditorPlugin`)? (I guess disabling them will solve this problem once for all.)
- Are there any better ways to achieve my needs, for example a media library module that can support a range of image storing services. (But that will also need some hack into the CKEditor, right?)

Comment: Maybe a workaround is extend `DrupalImage ` to use an external URL. This is a great candidate for a small contrib project.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This question was answer in the Drupal issue queue - https://www.drupal.org/node/2119379

> Reusing existing images will be possible in Drupal 8 contrib by
>   overriding the `managed_file` element, which is the element that renders
>   the image upload button. E.g.
>   https://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources does that: it provides a
>   "Reference existing" option.
>
> When you disable image uploads, you can insert image URLs. It's either
>   of the two, not both. If you want both, then again something like
>   https://drupal.org/project/filefield_sources provides the solution.